# ErrorNotice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to resolve an issue with the error message displayingon several pages through my site:

Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home/ihcukcom/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/innerpages.php on line 20

The site is wordpress hosted on third party. I have found the line of code outlined in above:

```
get_header(); ?>
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($page->ID), 'full' ); ?>
<section class="MainBanner position-relative bg-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $url; ?>')">   
&nbsp;
</section>
  <?php if(is_page(158)) { ?>
  <section id="InternalPage">
<div class="container">
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated as i'm a little out of my depth with this!

Mostly been looking at similar forum posts but each bit of code in the answers hasn't helped yet.

Comment: The message clearly says that `$page` is not an object.

Comment: Have you tried `$post->ID`. The variable in WordPress is usually $post, no matter what post-type.